# Rendering data with dynamic ids be used with jQuery effects in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails app, and there's a layer of complexity in how data in Rails table can be used to control certain actions by JS/jQuery that I am not grasping.

**What I am Trying to Do:** I have a table called `Comments`. Let's say it consists of values for `post` (the string of the comment), `slug` (which specifies a certain blog page it should appear on), and `location` (a string value that matches the id of a div on the page). Important: this div is dynamic - there will be a different number of divs on each page labeled "toc_0", "toc_1", and so on.

In the end, I would like to use jQuery's `.append()` or a similar effect (i.e. `prepend()`, `after()` to place a specific comment next to the div with an id that matches `location` on a page that matches `slug`.

**What I am Doing Now**: Showing comments that match the slug value is the easy part, obviously. I am doing that in my Controller like so:

```
class BlogsController < ActionController::Base

        @posts = Post.where(slug: params[:id]).all
        @comments = Comment.where(slug: params[:id]).all

end
```

In the view, I am rendering `@comments` with a normal loop - putting it in a column next to the post.

```
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
                <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
                <p id="category"><%= post.category %></p>
                <div id="paragraph"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>    
        <% end %>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
            <div class="card-1">
            <h5 class="testcomment"><%= comment.post %></h5> <h5 class="testauthor"></h5>
            </div>
        <% end %> 

    </div><!-- / column -->
```

**So Where Would the Targeting Happen?** I realize from that code, it probably is confusing how we would "target" a comment to a certain div in the post. That's because I am using the Markdown gem, and it labels each header as its own id in the DOM. Example live output for clarity:

```
 <h3 id="toc_0">Example Heading 1</h3>

     <p>Hello World, this is the first para</p>

 <h3 id="toc_1">Example Heading 2</h3>
```

When the page renders, I want the controller to not only render comments that match the page's slug (as it does now): I want it to append the comment next to the div id that matches the `location` column referenced above.

With these ids being dynamic, can I use jQuery to "target" the id without referencing "toc_0", "toc_1" etc., or does this need to be done with some controller magic?

Comment: Comments are going to be paired with the posts? As in you will have some posts that have comments next to them and some that won't based on the location?

Comment: Comments have a `belong_to` relationship with posts. That part is working. The next step is to show comments - when it renders - next to a specific part of a posting. A post may have three paragraphs, dynamically labeled `toc_0`, 'toc_1`, `toc_2`. There then may be one comment in the table for the post, and it has a `location` attribute of "toc_1". I want to render the comment next to `toc_1`.

Comment: darkginger. Did you give my answer a try?

Comment: @darkginger  Do you have a `slug` field in the `posts` table? Please post your schema.

Answer (score 3):

Something that would make this easier is if you added a `has_many: comments` in the posts model. Then for each Post you could do something where you look to see if it has a comment or set of comments associated with it.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
    <p id="category"><%= post.category %></p>
    <div id="paragraph"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <% if @post.comments.count > 0 %> 
      <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <div class="card-1">
          <h5 class="testcomment"><%= comment.post %></h5> <h5 class="testauthor"></h5>
        </div>
      <% end %> <!-- end each --> 
    <% end %> <!-- end if -->
  </div>
<% end %> <!-- end each post -->
```